# Does putting an include inside a function slow down execution?

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP function which requires authorization for a SOAP request to get the data and processes it. I like to keep the username/password outside of the program in auth.php and use an include statement like this:

```
include 'auth.php'; // Contains $username and $password.
```

I normally use include statement at the top of PHP programs. But I don't want to have to pass the values to the function so I put the include statement inside the function.

Does this slow down the program because it's reading auth.php each time the function gets called or does PHP read in all include files and keep the resident in the program, therefore not reading in the same auth.php file each time this function is called?

I have considered using DEFINE instead of setting the variables for username/password so they would be accessible through-out the program, but wasn't sure if this was necessary or not. Thanks!

Comment: functions accept params, use that feature to pass the username and password. don't include a file containing them. it's bad practice.

Comment: @Twisted1919 Can you explain why it's a bad practice?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons(unnecessary file dependency, black magic inside method, voodoo for developers trying to understand how it works, unable to be proper documented, etc). Just avoid it and write a proper method by using params.

Comment: A million `include` calls probably takes about as much time as a single SOAP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I really agree with what @Twisted1919 wrote in the comments, and I think you should listen to his advice, I'd also like to answer your question (does it slow down the execution?).

I'd say "not significantly", for a very simple reason: SOAP, even if done locally, hides XML encoding and parsing. Add to that the "processing of data" that you've mentioned, and you see that the overall work done by the function should amount to far more work than reading and parsing a PHP file that (presumably) only defines a few variables. Hence, that part is really insignificant.

Comment: OK, so it isn't an issue with performance execution time but the concern is the programming style in question. I agree, I will move it outside of the function since I too am concerned for the maintain ability of software and don't have a compelling reason to do something which is considered to be "strange". Thanks to all who commented!